# Exercism Robot Name, Constructors, and Jasmine Test Suite

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm totally missing something. I'm sure this is an easy one but not sure where I'm going wrong.

So this is the test I'm trying to run:

```
var Robot = require("./robot-name");

describe("Robot", function() {

  var robot;

  beforeEach(function() {
    robot = new Robot();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    robot = null;
  });

  it("has a name", function() {
    expect(robot.name).toMatch(/^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/);
  });
});
```

And here's the function I wrote:

```
function Robot() {
  var robotName = "CD123";

  function randomName() {
    return robotName;
  }

  return {
    name: randomName
  };
}
module.exports = Robot;
```

Whenever I run the test in the terminal, I get this message

```
Expected Function to match /^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/
```

Shouldn't I expect it to say `Expected "CD123" to match etc..` even if it doesn't pass the test?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomName` is a function that returns your string `"CD123"`. If you want to assign the string to your robot's `name` property instead of the function itself, you have to call the function:

```
function Robot() {
  var robotName = "CD123";

  function randomName() {
    return robotName;
 }

  return {
    name: randomName()
                    ^
   };
}
module.exports = Robot;
```

For a quick test, go to http://tddbin.com/# and paste your code there.